# Node JS and JIMP: No matching constructor overloading was

Tags: javascript, node.js, jimp

I'm trying to write some text on a simple jpg or png with nodejs and JIMP but i'm having issues on making it work.
The picture is gotten from a telegram bot, it gets merged with another picture with canvas and then i must write some simple text on it.

Here is my code:

```
const Jimp = require("jimp");
      var imageCaption = 'WRITE THIS ON PICTURE';
      var loadedImage;
      const image = await Jimp.read(finalCanvas)
        .then(function (image) {
        loadedImage = image;
        return Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_16_BLACK);
        })
        .then(function (font) {
            loadedImage.print(font, 10, 10, imageCaption)
            .write(finalCanvas);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
```

I keep getting an error about a matching contstructor overloading not found.
Also had troubles getting JIMP read my local files.

Complete error i get:

```
Error: No matching constructor overloading was found. Please see the docs for how to call the Jimp constructor.
    at Jimp.throwError (/home/smp0/ifsbadge/node_modules/@jimp/utils/dist/index.js:33:13)
    at new Jimp (/home/smp0/ifsbadge/node_modules/@jimp/core/dist/index.js:412:85)
    at _construct (/home/smp0/ifsbadge/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/construct.js:19:21)
    at /home/smp0/ifsbadge/node_modules/@jimp/core/dist/index.js:926:32
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Function.Jimp.read (/home/smp0/ifsbadge/node_modules/@jimp/core/dist/index.js:925:10)
    at TelegramBot.<anonymous> (/home/smp0/ifsbadge/index.js:51:32)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  methodName: 'constructor'
}
```

Complete context:

```
var needle = require('needle');
const Telegram = require('node-telegram-bot-api')
const { createCanvas, loadImage, ImageData } = require('canvas')
var Jimp = require("jimp");
var fs = require('fs');
const factions = {}


token="1234:BLABLA"
const bot = new Telegram(token, { polling: true })

bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
  if (msg.photo) {
    if (factions[msg.chat.id]) {
      console.log(`Generating badge for ${msg.from.first_name} (${msg.from.username})...`)
      bot.sendChatAction(msg.chat.id, 'upload_photo').catch(console.error)
      const pictureCanvas = createCanvas(559, 772)
      const pictureCtx = pictureCanvas.getContext('2d')
      const { file_path } = await bot.getFile(msg.photo[msg.photo.length - 1].file_id)
      const picture = await loadImage(`https://api.telegram.org/file/bot${token}/${file_path}`)
      

    // PICTURE CALCULATIONS
      pheight = picture.height
      pwidth = picture.width
      aspectratiow = (pwidth/pheight)
      aspectratioh = (pheight/pwidth)
      oheight = pheight*aspectratioh
      owidth = (pwidth) / (pwidth/559)
      newheight = 559*pheight/pwidth     
      var scale = Math.min(559/pwidth, 772/pheight);
      var posx = (559 / 2) - (559 / 2) * scale;
      var posy = (772 / 2) - (pheight / 2) * scale;
    // END OF CALCULATIONS
      
    // MERGING TWO PICTURES
      pictureCtx.drawImage(picture, 10 , posy, 559, newheight)
      const finalCanvas = createCanvas(559, 772)
      const finalCtx = finalCanvas.getContext('2d')
      const frame = await loadImage(`./frames/${factions[msg.chat.id]}.png`)
      finalCtx.drawImage(pictureCanvas, 0, 0, 559, 772)
      finalCtx.drawImage(frame, 0, 0, 559, 772)
      factions[msg.chat.id] = null
    // END OF MERGING PICTURES
      
    //APPLYING TEXT ON PICTURE
      
      const Jimp = require("jimp");
      var imageCaption = 'WRITE THIS ON PICTURE';
      var loadedImage;
      const image = await Jimp.read(finalCanvas)
        .then(function (image) {
        loadedImage = image;
        return Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_16_BLACK);
        })
        .then(function (font) {
            loadedImage.print(font, 10, 10, imageCaption)
            .write(finalCanvas);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    //END OF APPLYING TEXT ON PICTURE
      
      
      bot.sendPhoto(msg.chat.id, finalCanvas.toBuffer('image/jpeg', { quality: 1 }))
    } else {
      bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Write /enl1 /enl2 /enl3 o /res1 /res2 /res3 o /xf1 /xf2 !').catch(console.log)
    }
  }
})

bot.onText(/\/start/, async (msg) => {
  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Welcome! Select your badge Write /enl1 /enl2 /enl3 o /res1 /res2 /res3 o /xf1 /xf2 !").catch(console.log)
})

bot.onText(/\/(enl1|enl2|enl3|res1|res2|res3|xf1|xf2)/, async (msg, match) => {
  factions[msg.chat.id] = match[1]
  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Good! Now send me your picture').catch(console.log)
})
```

srcs on github: https://github.com/pedrofracassi/badgemaker and https://github.com/FerdinandoLM/IngressFSBadgeMaker

Comment: Using a locally saved file with

```picurl=`https://api.telegram.org/file/bot${token}/${file_path}`
picname = "test.jpg"
var https = require('https');
var file = fs.createWriteStream(`pics/${picname}.jpg`);
var request = https.get(picurl, function(response) {
response.pipe(file);
});```

and using 
```Jimp.read(`pics/${picname}.jpg`)```

 gives 

```Error: Could not find MIME for Buffer <null>```

as error

Comment: not entirely sure, can u post the code in the question?

Comment: @seanplwong sure, here it is: https://pastebin.com/BtNqz4fE i have to use pastebin due to character limit on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, `finalCanvas` is an instance of `Canvas`. I don't think `Jimp` would take an instance of `Canvas`, but `Canvas#toBuffer()` might be the thing you want as `Jimp` would take a buffer: `Jimp.read(finalCanvas.toBuffer())`

---

Both `http.get` and `response.pipe(writeStream)` are asynchronous. At the time you try `Jimp.read`, the file isn't in the file system yet or it is not completely written onto disk.

To do it after file is written, listen to `finish` event.

```
file.on('finish', async () => {
  await Jump.read(...);
});
```

Comment: Already did that but ended with a Error: path must be a string. So i used fs to actually save a file and give the path to JIMP, but got a ERRNOENT, caused by the fact that Jimp seemed to not find the file.